# Get new created data back

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

Is it possible to get the data you just saved back from Firebase via AngularFire2? 
I want to have the saved data with it's generated UUID.

I'm saving the data like this:

```
const phase = this.fireStore.collection("pr").doc(prId).collection("col1").doc(phase)
        phase.collection("content").add({"content": post.content})
```

Now I want to return the saved data back as an Observable that has a map for my custom object.

What I now have is that I first convert it to an Observable and then I do the get via valueChanges.

To me this seems like overkill.

Comment: Or you have to subscribe on 'this.fireStore.collection("pr").doc(prId).collection("col1")' before add new data and unsubscribe when you got new content that you just add.

Comment: is that really the best option?

Comment: I have waiting for an another option too..

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting it done like this:

```
const phase = this.fireStore.collection("projects").doc(post.projectId).collection("canvas1").doc(post.phase)
return from(phase.collection("content").add({ "content": post.content })).pipe(map(ref => {
  return new Post(ref.id, post.content)
}))
```

if someone knows a better way please share :-)